# How can I open a modal by click on one of the bottom Navigation item?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to click on one of the Botton Navigation item then it will open the `showModalBottomSheet` with content on it.

I can't seems to find a solution for this one, how can I achieve this in Flutter?

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      onTap: _selectPage,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.event_available_rounded),
          label: 'Events',
        )]),
```

I try to call the model like this

```
if (_selectedPageIndex == 1) {
  activePage = openEventReportOverlay();
  activePageTitle = 'Report';
}


void openEventReportOverlay() {
  showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context, builder: (ctx) => const EventScreen());
}
```

I got an error `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see everything working properly, full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: _selectPage,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: 'One',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.event_available_rounded),
            label: 'Events',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    if (index == 1) {
      _openModalEvent();
    }
  }

  void _openModalEvent() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const EventScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class EventScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EventScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text("Events Page"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
activePage = openEventReportOverlay();
```

to

```
openEventReportOverlay();
```

Comment: I got the following error when I do that: 
`Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget dur...`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the minimum viable code. - 50 lines of fully functional source code.

Source code:

```
class NewHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewHomePage> createState() => _NewHomePageState();
}

class _NewHomePageState extends State<NewHomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one), label: "1"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two), label: "2"),
        ],
        onTap: (int value) async {
          currentIndex = value;
          setState(() {});
          if (currentIndex == 0) {
          } else {
            await openModalBottomSheet();
          }
        },
      ),
      body: const SafeArea(child: SizedBox()),
    );
  }

  Future<void> openModalBottomSheet() async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => const Event(),
    );
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}

class Event extends StatelessWidget {
  const Event({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(child: Text("Hello there!"));
  }
}
```